# Content type oneTimeCode is not working in swift with IQkeyboard manager

Tags: ios, swift, one-time-password

I want to display the OTP code in my text field I search in google and get the following code.

In my application I using IQkeyboard manager

But OTP autofill is not working for me.

```
@IBOutlet weak var otp: CustomTextField!    
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
                otp.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
     }
```

i getting meesage following way.

```
Your ***** verification code is :969514
```

Comment: please check your code by disabling IQKeyboard for that specific view.

Comment: I already try with hide the IQKeyboard manager also but I don't getting

Comment: i think the class/library you are using for textfield is creating issue. use simple textField or other library/class for textfield.

Answer (score 7):

For `Auto Fill` to work you need to keep few things in mind,

1. Your `SMS` should have the word **code**(e.g, ***security code***,
   ***verification code***) to be recognized by the Auto Fill for value
   extraction.
2. Leverage the system keyboard rather than implementing a keyboard
   directly in your app's view hierarchy([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)).
3. If you use a custom input view for a security code input text field,
   iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)).

Comment: @ghrixghrix I would suggest create a test View where you use native `UITextField` and see if it works as expected.